# How can I set the number of ticks in Julia using Pyplot?

Tags: matplotlib, julia

I am struggling to 'translate' the instructions I find for Python to the use of Pyplot in Julia. This must be a simple question, but do you know how to set the number of ticks in a plot in Julia using Pyplot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trying and searching, I found a way to do it. One can just set the number of bins that should be on each axis. Here is a minimal example:

```
using PyPlot
x = linspace(0, 10, 200)
y = sin(x)
fig, ax = subplots()
ax[:plot](x, y, "r-", linewidth=2, label="sine function", alpha=0.6)
ax[:legend](loc="upper center")
ax[:locator_params](axis ="y", nbins=4)
```

The last line specifies the number of bins that should be used on the y-axis. Leaving the argument axis unspecified will set that option for both axis at the same value.

Answer (score 6):

If you have

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [1,3,6,8,11]
```

you can

```
PyPlot.plot(x,y)
```

which draws the plot

and then do

```
PyPlot.xticks([1,3,5])
```

for tics at 1,3 and 5 on the x-axis

```
PyPlot.yticks([1,6,11])
```

for tics at 1,6 and 11 on the y-axis

**Tic spacing**

if you want fx 4 tics and want it evenly spaced and dont mind Floats, you can do

```
collect(linspace(x[1], x[end], 4).
```

If you need the tics to be integers and you want 4 tics, you can do

```
collect(x[1]:div(x[end],4):x[end])
```

**Edit**

Maybe this wont belong here but atleast you'll see it...

whenever you're looking for a method that's supposed to be in a module X you can find these methods by typing in the REPL X. + TAB key

to clarify, if you want to search a module for a method you suspect starts with an x, like xticts, in the REPL (terminal/shell) do

```
PyPlot.x
```

and press TAB twice and you'll see

```
julia> PyPlot.x
xkcd   xlabel  xlim    xscale  xticks
```

and if you're not sure exactly how the method works, fx its arguments, and there isnt any help available, you can call

```
methods(PyPlot.xticks)
```

to see every "version" that method has

**Bonus**

The module for all the standard methods, like maximum, vcat etc is Base

Comment: missing the k in ticks?

Comment: Thank you, this is already quite helpful. As I have a number of plots for which different ticks would be optimal, I would like to specify the number of ticks instead of defining the ticks themselves. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: if you want fx 4 tics and want it evenly spaced and dont mind Floats, you can do collect(linspace(x[1], x[end], 4).
If you need the tics to be integers and you want 4 tics, you can do collect(x[1]:div(x[end],4):x[end])

Comment: That is exactly what I do not want to do, as a different range is appropriate for each plot. I found this possibility to do that in Python: http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator

This would place a number of ticks in "nice locations". What would be the correct way to implement that in Julia?